# Finding out how many items fit in the QTreeView (number of rows visible on the screen)

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I'm sure there's an easy way to get this number, but can't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be determined for empty view because it can vary depending on items' content. If there are already items in the view, you can calculate `QAbstractItemView::visualRect` and intersect it to `viewport()`'s `rect()` to see if a particular item is visible. So you can iterate over rows and check if an item is visible. For example:

```
for(int row = 0; row < view.model()->rowCount(); row++) {
  if (!view.visualRect(view.model()->index(row, 0)).intersects(view.viewport()->rect())) {
    return row;
  }
}
```

However this only works if you have only top level items and you have enough items to fill the viewport.

Alternatively, you can call `view.indexAt(QPoint(0, 0))` and `view.indexAt(QPoint(0, view.viewport()->height()))` and compare indexes. However if these indexes don't share the same parent, counting rows will become troublesome.

Comment: All my items are top-level items with no children. Can I somehow calculate the height of one item and divide the viewport's height by it?

Comment: You can, it will be `view.viewport()->height() /  view.visualRect(view.model()->index(0, 0)).height()`. But it will not be precise because the viewport has padding and it depends on widget's style and cannot be determined easily.

Comment: Also, if they are all top-level, why not use `QTableView` or `QListView` instead?

Comment: I guess `QTableView` would do the job, I just never used it and wasn't aware it even existed until recently.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? `numItemsVisible = indexAt(geometry().topLeft()).row() - indexAt(geometry().bottomRight()).row();` It always gives 1, and if I use `viewport()->geometry()` (instead of `QTreeView::geometry()` it gives 3, while there are like 30 visible items.

Comment: `itemAt` takes viewport coordinates, while `viewport()->geometry()` is in the view coordinates and `geometry()` is in the view's parent coordinates (which is even more irrelevant). It would be correct to use `viewport()->rect()` instead, though `viewport()->rect()->topLeft()` equals (0, 0).

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of Pavel Strakhov's answer, I think I managed to reformulate the code so that it doesn't need a `for` loop over all the items and thus is O(1) instead of O(N) (where N is the number of items in the model):

```
int CFileListView::numRowsVisible() const
{
    const auto viewportRect = viewport()->rect();
    const auto topIndex = indexAt(QPoint{ 10, viewportRect.top() + 1 });
    const auto bottomIndex = indexAt(QPoint{ 10, viewportRect.bottom() - 1 });

    if (!topIndex.isValid())
    {
        // If topIndex is not valid, bottomIndex should be invalid as well,
        // otherwise there's a situation I have not encountered and it should be looked into.
        assert(!bottomIndex.isValid());
        return 0;
    }

    if (bottomIndex.isValid())
       return bottomIndex.row() - topIndex.row();
    else
       return model()->rowCount() - topIndex.row();
}
```

It's inside my subclass of a `QTreeView` so `this` is a `QTreeView`.
`10` is an arbitrary margin and probably should be adjusted to the lowest value that works; `0` does not work.